# How can I solve this DB2 Driver Error for my NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, db2, driver, db2-luw

I am trying to run a nodejs app which uses node module ibm_db and connects to a db2 db on IBM Cloud. When I try to run it I get the following error message

> [2019-02-28T09:20:35.400] [ERROR] [Ldap Config] - { Error: [IBM][CLI
>   Driver] SQL30081N  Se ha detectado un error en las comunicaciones.
>   Protocolo de comunicaciones que se está utilizando: "SSL".  API de
>   comunicaciones que se está utilizando: "SOCKETS".  Ubicación donde se
>   ha encontrado el error: "".  Función de comunicación que ha detectado
>   el error: "sqlcctcpconnr".  Código(s) de error específico(s) del
>   protocolo: "202", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
>
> errors: [],   error: '[node-odbc] SQL_ERROR',   message: '[IBM][CLI
>   Driver] SQL30081N  Se ha detectado un error en las comunicaciones.
>   Protocolo de comunicaciones que se está utilizando: "SSL".  API de
>   comunicaciones que se está utilizando: "SOCKETS".  Ubicación donde se
>   ha encontrado el error: "".  Función de comunicación que ha detectado
>   el error: "sqlcctcpconnr".  Código(s) de error específico(s) del
>   protocolo: "202", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001\r\n',   state: '08001',
>   sqlcode: -30081 } [2019-02-28T09:20:35.400] [WARN] log - [Thu, 28 Feb
>   2019 12:20:35 GMT[clf]] - false - "GET
>   /auth/sso/callback?scope=openid&code=7wZVobhvNcVMeF3df3v9JWAI6pwFwf"
>   302 80 1141 ms'

I heard it could be related to the DB2 Driver that I could have (that the app conflicts with the local driver and that in fact it should not be installed) However I need it for other proyect (this is a new project with which I was required to work)

I have the following DB2 version

> DB21085I  La instancia "DB2" utiliza "64" bits y el release de código
>   de DB2 "SQL09074" con el identificador de nivel "08050107". Las
>   señales informativas son "DB2 v9.7.400.501", "s110330", "IP23238" y
>   FixPack "4". El producto está instalado en "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB"
>   con nombre de copia de DB2 "DB2COPY1".

I am honestly lost with this error. Any help will be much appreciated.

----------UPDATE-------------

Adding the server/config/dev.json

```
"sso": {
      "authorization_url": "/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/authorize",
      "token_url": "/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/token",
      "issuerId": "https://prepiam.toronto.ca.ibm.com",
      "callback_url": "/auth/sso/callback",
      "clientId": secret
      "clientSecret": secret
    },
    "slack": {
      "webhookURL": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/more_secret_stuff?"
    },
    "db2": {
      "dsn": "DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=dashdb-entry-yp-dal10-01.services.dal.bluemix.net;PORT=50001;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=id;PWD=pass;Security=SSL;"
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: The 202 protocol error means "202 – Unable to open the key file. Either the path was specified incorrectly or the file permissions did not allow the file to be opened."  EDIT your question to add the URL/uri details, how you specify the key/certificate etc.

Comment: Your local database version seems to be v9.7. Are you trying to use that driver to connect to a Db2 on Cloud?

Comment: Thanks @mao, could you please clarify what key/certificate I should look for? is it related to the db2 driver or to the app itself?

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik, I suppose I am using that driver in order to connect to the DB. Is there a way to check it or somewhere I could confirm? It is the only DB2 Driver I have installed...

Comment: You have not answered the question: what is your URL for the database? The certificate normally belongs to the target Db2-server instance. For Db2-client *older than Version 10.5 fixpack 5* you have to *configure* the Db2-client (and the URL used for connection)  to specify that certificate (for example, in a keystore). BUT cloud services may impose a minimum Db2-client *version/fixpack* and a minimum level of TLS.   CHECK WITH IBM for exact requirements for CLI clients SSL/TLS for whatever cloud service you are using. This is NOT a programming matter, it is configuration.

Comment: Hi, an update on this...I've originaly added the parameters with Port: 50000 and without ssl setting. That worked, the app could connect without issues. So it is related to the certificates. I would need to find the certs folder and see how it is configured

Answer (score 0):

dashdb lets you connect to its database with (or without) SSL (TLS).

Many companies prefer to encrypt their database communications if using a cloud based database, both for data in-flight and at rest. Some industries mandate this.

dashdb may require a minimum version of TLS (SSL) for example v1.2.

I don't know if the Db2 v9.7.4 Windows client supports TLSV12, and if not, whether the SSL handshake can negotiate a lower version successfully for dashdb. IF it does not, then your options are upgrade or don't encrypt.

Your best bet might be to bite the bullet: install and use a current V11.1.4.4 Db2-client which you can download from IBM Passport Advantage (or get within your company). Your company might be forced to do this Db2-client upgrade at some point anyway. It's also possible to have more than one Db2-client installed on the same machine, and to switch between them although you need to test it carefully.

You can get the dashdb cerficiate from IBM, sometimes via downloading from the web console.

If you wish to persist with the Db2 v9.7.4 client (to see if it can work with SSL for dashdb - it might not!), instructions for that version are [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0053518.html) . IBM did not make it easy in those older versions, which is one reason to upgrade (because current versions don't need a GSK to be installed separately, and don't need you to create/populate a keystore).